# How to use tf.maybe_batch to switch between train/val pipelines?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a pipeline to read train and validation datasets from `tfrecords`.
I build batches using `tf.train.batch`. During training I want to switch between training and evaluation on validation dataset.

Here is simplified snippet of code how I implement it now.

```
is_training_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.bool) 
images_train, labels_train = tf.train.batch([img_train, label_train])
images_val, labels_val = tf.train.batch([img_val, label_val])

data = tf.cond(is_training_pl, lambda: [images_train, labels_train], lambda: [images_val, labels_val])

loss = my_model(input=data)
```

I know that one can do it with `tf.cond`, but the problem with it is that both train and val batch ops would be executed when `tf.cond` is called.
On github **ebrevdo** told ([link to the comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2514#issuecomment-272605153)) that it's possible to use `tf.train.maybe_batch` for this purpose instead, which is more efficient.

Can anyone give an example of how to use `tf.train.batch` in my case please?